# Set a shortcut for opening Terminator (similar to Ctrl+Alt+T, but not replacing default terminal)

Tags: 14.04, command-line, gnome-terminal, terminator

I have both terminator and the default terminal installed (under Ubuntu 14.04). I have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> linked to the default terminal which is fine and should remain as is. Now I also would like to use terminator (i.e. have several terminals using different terminal emulators at the same time).

How do I call terminator when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> is already linked to the default terminal? Is there a way to setup <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> as the default shortcut to terminator (and keep <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> as the shortcut for the default terminal)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Settings, look for the shortcuts menu and if you are there, there should be a button with a "+" sign. Press it and it should bring you to a page where you can give the shortcut a command, the shortcut you want to invoke the that command with, and a name.

For the command set "terminator" without quotes and for the shortcut set Ctrl-Alt-Y.

To have Ctrl-Alt-T launch gnome-terminal disable the original terminal shortcut, and create a new one with the command "gnome-terminal" and the shortcut Ctrl-Alt-T.